# Sudo command not found OS X Yosemite

Tags: port, sudo

I am really new to using macintosh, Kinect and sensors and I am trying to install drivers of Kinect Xbox on my mac OS X Yosemite v. 10.10.5 and I found out that I should install OpenNI, SensorKinect and NITE. I am trying first to install some libraries, so as to move on with the installation, using the command: sudo port install libtool.
However, when I type it, what I take is this:
sudo: port: command not found.

I have also tried to check my PATH, but it didn't help.
I have searched everywhere I could to find out why this happens, but I didn't manage to find an answer. Could you please help me?

Comment: Have you installed macports?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,                                                                                I just installed macports and used the following commands to install the prerequisite libraries :  -v self update, libtool,  libusb-devel +universal, boost, wxWidgets-devel,                                                                           At the last one though, what I get is: Error: Port wxWidgets-devel not found. I searched what might be wrong, but I didn't manage to find an answer.

Comment: I solved it using sudo /opt/local/bin/port install wxWidgets-3.0

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using sudo /opt/local/bin/port install wxWidgets-3.0